# Is it possible to do all these on an Android phone?

Tags: android

I am wondering is it possible to do all these on an Android phone? Example, Samsung Galaxy S phone

1. To automatically launch a video clip upon phone start up i.e. from off position or phone ‘reboot’/’restart’
2. To run the video clip while the phone is idling
3. To launch to a particular wap site when interrupted
4. To restrict user from going to other portal other than the 3 steps above
5. To restrict user from running other application on the phone.

Comment: "possibilities"? The question would more aptly be titled: "How can I make all these things impossible on an Android phone"? Just take the kernel and write your own OS already. You'll be king of the universe and no-one will buy your phone!

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes but it may be hard to completely replace the phone's own screens and animation effects thus giving the smooth experience I think you're looking for. It's also pretty user-hostile.

2) What is 'idling'? If you mean standby, absolutely not. You'd kill the battery in 20 minutes in any case.

3) You can launch a website when the phone comes out of standby but it would be really annoying for the user. As for WAP .. I have no idea if you can view WAP on Android. Probably someone has made a viewer. I wasn't aware WAP was being used by anyone since some time around 2008.

4) Not without making your own custom build of Android and flashing it (*very* difficult technically). Sounds pretty evil for the user.

5) Again, not without making your own custom build of Android. You're reducing the phone to a brick pretty much with this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, though it is user-hostile.
2. I have no idea what you are talking about.
3. I have no idea what you are talking about.
4. No, except by making your own firmware. Even by replacing the home screen, the user can boot into the Android equivalent of "safe mode" and bypass a replacement home screen app. You would need to have your home screen be the only one on the device, and your apps be the only one on the device.
5. See #4.

Answer (score 0):

I will add only to question (1), since all the questions have been already answered. If you talk about replacing the standard boot and shutdown animations, then yes, it is very possible and pretty much any custom ROM for the SGS will let you do that. It's just a matter of assembling the sequence of PNG files you want. There are two image flashes before the animation, one is built-in in the bootloader, the other is hardcoded on the kernel.

Examples: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=869347

Answer (score 0):

You can do all these things, however you will need to flash a custom image - I assume you want to customise in-house handsets for a specific project, rather than have this as a generic app - I can't imagine normal users installing this kind of lockdown, and it sounds similar to an approach I was looking at for a project needing cheap PDAs with GSM connectivity.

If that's the case, and volumes are low, you might be better off targeting developer handsets, which can be bought through a publisher account on Android Market. I think this limits you to 10 handsets.

Hope this helps,

Phil Lello